# Mercurial - repos with multiple ACL rules

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook

I'm trying to use 2 set of rules for the ACL of my repos. I was thinking that maybe the action name could be useful from the hooks section but that not the case.

The rules are :

1) Only be able to commit on a specific branch (ex: acceptance)

2) Only be able to pull a specific branch. (Ex: `bigNewFeature`)

The second rule can look strange for a repo. We are in middle of releasing a big project where all the branches related to it had been merge under `bigNewFeature` for months on it. We are pushing it on our acceptance server and want to freeze the repos of any new branches except for `bigNewFeature`. That pretty much to avoid any mistake from one of the dev.

```
[extensions]
hgext.acl=

[hooks]
pretxncommit.acl = python:hgext.acl.hook

# Was expecting to be able to use any action name
pretxncommit.aclpull = python:hgext.acl.hook
# OR
pretxnchangegroup.aclpull = python:hgext.acl.hook

[acl]
sources = commit

[acl.allow.branches] 
acceptance = *

[aclpull]
sources = pull

[aclpull.allow.branches] 
bigNewFeature = *
```

My first rule work like usual but the second one don't look to be run at all. I have no error or what ever.

Comment: Can you add a little more info... what happens when you tried this?